# Special case for first item when looping through array and getting previous value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm currently doing this, to store the height of each item to later access it via `css`:

```
children[0].style.setProperty('--previousHeight', 0+'px');
children.forEach((child, i) => {
    if(i > 0 ){
        var height = children[i-1].offsetHeight;
        child.style.setProperty('--previousHeight', height+'px');
    }
})
```

I would like to treat the first item more like the other once. Something like

```
height = offsetHeight || 0;
```

But i'm not sure how I can do it in a easy to read way

Comment: cause I want the value to be the value of the previous child and for i = 0 there is no value.

Comment: `if (i > 0) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: so you want to set --previousHeight on the first child of index 0 with a value of 0px ?

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```js
children.forEach((child, i) => {
    var height = children[i-1] && children[i-1].offsetHeight || 0;
    child.style.setProperty('--previousHeight', height+'px');
})
```

If you're not familiar with:

```
var height = children[i-1] && children[i-1].offsetHeight || 0;
```

It gives the same result as:

```
var height = children[i-1] ? children[i-1].offsetHeight : 0;
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because child is not defined for first iteration i = [0-1]

Comment: Exactly it's undefined, and `children[i - 1] && children[i - 1].offsetHeight || 0` evaluates to 0

Comment: no Faly, I think you mean `height = children[i-1] ? children[i-1].offsetHeight : 0`

Comment: that evaluates to either `false` or `true`

Comment: @Noface it does the same thing as Faly wrote

Comment: @Noface It's just the same as The Reason said.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the quickest and cleanest way.

```
<div id='myElement'>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</diV>
<script>
    var children = document.getElementById('myElement').children;
    var h = children[0].offsetHeight;
    for(var i in children){
        if( i > 0 ){
            children[i].style['height'] = h;
            children[i].style.setProperty('--previousHeight', h);                
        }            
    }
</script>
```

Comment: And the `children[0].style.setProperty('--previousHeight', 0+'px');`?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
    children.forEach((child, i) => {
        var height = 0 
        if(i > 0 ){
            var height = children[i-1].offsetHeight;
        }
        child.style.setProperty('--previousHeight', height+'px');
    })
```